# Additional address-related fields that vary for each country - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, street-address

### Issue/Concern

I am trying to implement a dynamic address form like the Amazon addresses page.

For example, for ***United States***, these are the fields that will be displayed:

> [image: United States Address Form]

On the other hand, ***Australia*** will display these fields:

> [image: Australia Address Form]

Other countries:

***China***:

> [image: China Address Form]

***Canada***:

> [image: Canada Address Form]

### Question

I would like to ask if any Javascript libraries will determine additional address-related fields that vary for each country. Or any idea on how to achieve this will do.

I'm not really sure if I did provide enough details about my problem, but I would be glad to add more information if needed. Thank you very much!

I tried to search Javascript address libraries, but none of them fit my needs.